# Porque o JSF não reconhece o id do componente na View?

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces

O JSF não está reconhecendo o id "dialogo-analise" que está na view e está dando o erro :

```
FATAL: Cannot find component for expression "dialogo-analise" referenced from "frmAtividade:tab:itens-rh:0:j_idt275".javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component for expression "dialogo-analise" referenced from "frmAtividade:tab:itens-rh:0:j_idt275".
```

Código que estou chamado o

```
<p:commandLink title="Registrar Análise"
        oncomplete="PF('edicaoAnaliseRH').show()"
        action="#{atividadeBean.iniciarAnaliseRH(rh.id,rh.cpf)}"
        process="@this" update="dialogo-analise">
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/setas_2544_Run2.png" width="17"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Quando retiro o id do dialog "dialogo-analise", funciona mas não faz o que preciso. Eu estou usando o tabView do primefaces e o botão está dentro de uma datatable, no qual e seleciono uma linha. 
Existe um método no meu bean que chamo antes de  abrir o diálogo. Seleciono alguns dados na tabela e tento exibir neste diálogo. Debugando os dados são atribuidos aos setters dos atributos, mas não são exibidos.... muito estranho.

Código do diálogo

```
<p:dialog id="dialogo-analise" widgetVar="edicaoAnaliseRH" resizable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true">
```

Comment: Esse problema está acontecendo no update?

Comment: Sim, quando incluo o id do diálogo, ele dá o erro que o componente não existe

Comment: O problema não é ele reconhecer o id, ele não está encontrando o id. Eles estão dentro de um mesmo form?

Comment: Sim, estão dentro do mesmo form.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa a ver com o tabView?

Comment: Poste seu código para ver como está hierarquia da sua pagina.

Comment: Provavelmente esse é o componente que está faltando o ID: `j_idt275`

Comment: Faça um teste dessa forma: `update="j_idt275:dialogo-analise"`

Comment: j_idt275 é provavelmente o o commandLink dele, precisa ver onde tá o dialog dele pra colocar o caminho correto no update do commandLink

Comment: Se estiver fora da tabview provavelmente é  `update=":frmAtividade:dialogo-analise" `

Comment: Rafael, funcionou da forma que descreveu. Eu coloquei o dialogo fora do tabView.... agora me restou um outro problema. Quando eu finalizava a atualização desta tela eu atualizava um datatable que estava dentro de um tab. Agora não atualiza mais pelo fato de eu ter tirado o dialogo do tab. Para eu atualizar esta datatable eu preciso informar todo o caminho desta id, por exemplo: frmAtividade:tabview:tab:datatable?

Comment: Sim, ou você pode atualizar a tabview inteira(se necessário). vou postar uma reposta com a solução.

Comment: Rafael, blz.... deu certo muito obrigado pela ajuda! Abraços

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não é ele reconhecer o id mas sim ele não está encontrando o caminho correto do id do `dialog`.

o caminho correto seria `update=":frmAtividade:dialogo-analise"`.

Alguns componentes é necessário fazer isso, como por exemplo `tabView` , `dataTable` e `dialog`, ao fazer um update para fora deles é necessário colocar o caminho, iniciando pelo id do form, até o componente desejado.

Uma alternativa é usar `update="#{p:component('idComponente')}"`